# How to get the error report of valgrind?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

First I run like this:

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all test_proc`

and logs:

```
==30349== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30349== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

so I run with `-v`

`valgrind -v --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all test_proc`

and logs:

```
==8020== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8020== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I cannot find other error keyword. Where is the error?

Comment: Is that only 2 lines the full report? Have you tried `--log-file=` which write the report in a file, useful when terminal is garbled

Comment: Yes, i used `--log-file`, there's only these two lines contain `error` word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out, `7` stands for the total count of `possibly lost` and `definitely lost` records.